# foreach within foreach in razor view not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, parse-error

I had a partial view as shown below in which i have first foreach loop for posts and another foreach to add comments for that post. But the run time error is as

> Parser Error Message :Unexpected "foreach" keyword after "@"
>   character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs
>   like "foreach" with "@".

but the braces are perfect.

```
       @model Network.Models.ViewPostModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddPost", "Network"))
{

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.addpost.Content, new { @class = "textboxstyle"})
        <br/>
         <button type="submit">Add Post </button>
           <br/><br/>
           @foreach(var post in Model.Post)
           {
            <br/>
             <b>Posted by :</b> @post.Username
            <span> @post.Content </span> 
                @foreach(var comment in Model.Comments)
                {

                        <br/>
                       @comment.Content
                    <b>Comented  by :</b> @comment.username
                      <br/><br/>
               }
          @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.addcomment.Content)
          <button type="submit">Add Comment </button>

        }
}
```

I tried either one foreach loop is working but not both .My Model class for strongly typed partial view is as below

```
public class ViewPostModel
    {

            public List<Post> Post { get; set; }
            public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
            public List<UserFriend> Userfriends { get; set; }
            public Post addpost { get; set; }
            public Comment addcomment { get; set; }

    }
```

Please check what my fault is in?

Thanks,
michaeld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the `fieldset` inside `foreach` and you're closing it outside.

I've seen similar problems with razor. e.g. check this post
[The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666440/the-foreach-block-is-missing-a-closing-character/9666495#9666495)

And it doesn't make sense to me - you should move the first/opening outside the loop I think.

Comment: i think problem is not with fieldset , i edited removing it and also removed div tags , but still not working , one foreach is working fine , now the error message changed and also modified it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946334/unexpected-foreach-keyword-after-character   this worked for me thanks

Comment: btw - it's not how SO works - if you find one error - you comment that, make an edit, pointing to another error - **but don't just remove it completely** turning it into a new error/question - as my answer then looks a bit foolish (but solved your original error spot on)

Comment: ohh i am sorry , i am very new to stackoverflow