# Razor parse error- nested if and html within a foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to execute the following code in asp.net razor view-

```
@foreach (var contact in ViewBag.ContactInfo.Rows)
{
    if (columnCount>4)
    {
        <div class="row-fluid">
    }

    <div class="span4">@ViewBag.SomeText</div>

    //This if block is treated as normal text.
    if (columnCount > 4)
    {
        </div>
        columnCount = 0;
    }

    columnCount++;
}
```

But it gives parse error.

Any help?

Comment: Which error you are getting?

Comment: @ramiramilu Last if block is treated as normal text.

Comment: There is unclosed html tag in you razor condition . Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809694/razor-doesnt-understand-unclosed-html-tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach (var contact in ViewBag.ContactInfo.Rows)
{
    if (columnCount>4)
    {
       @:<div class="row-fluid">
    }

   <div class="span4">@ViewBag.SomeText</div>

   //This if block is treated as normal text.
   if (columnCount > 4)
   {
      @:</div>
      columnCount = 0;
   }

   columnCount++;
```

}

Comment: why the @:, what is it used for

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below. As you are opening `div` tag in one if and closing in other, razor viewengine is somehow not able to parse it. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666440/the-foreach-block-is-missing-a-closing-character) for more

```
      @foreach (var contact in ViewBag.ContactInfo.Rows)
        {
            if (columnCount>4)
            {
                <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4">@ViewBag.SomeText</div>
                </div>
            }

            else
            {
                <div class="span4">@ViewBag.SomeText</div>
            }
            columnCount++;
        }
```

Comment: Then first if block says -'} missing'.